# Meteor + React: Show different Navigation items depending on the login state

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-1.4

I have a **Meteor** + React Application where I have a Header class like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { NavLoggedIn } from './header/NavLoggedIn'
import { NavLoggedOut } from './header/NavLoggedOut'

export class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header className="main-header">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                    <div className="navbar-custom-menu">
                        <NavLoggedIn />
                        <NavLoggedOut />
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

I've got an accounts system that works nicely but now I want to change the appearance of the `NavBar` based off of whether or not the user is logged in.

How could I accomplish this?

**I.E.**

If the **Meteor** user is logged in show the `<NavLoggedIn />` component. Otherwise, show the `<NavLoggedOut />` component.

Comment: Is there any prop to define whether the user is online or not?

Comment: No, I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: there might be a prop coming from another component, please show the full code.

Comment: There isn't a prop coming from another component, I don't know how to implement it.  I just want to know how to set it based on whether or not a Meteor user is logged in.  I can see the ID of the use by typing `Meteor.userId()` in the console.

Comment: wait i am looking at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'` and add the following to your `render()` function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor

import { NavLoggedIn } from './header/NavLoggedIn'
import { NavLoggedOut } from './header/NavLoggedOut'

export class Header extends Component {
    render() {
       let navigate;
        // If Meteor.userID() is null then render <NavLoggedOut />, otherwise <NavLoggedIn />
        if(Meteor.userId())
          navigate=<NavLoggedIn />;
        else
          navigate=<NavLoggedOut />
        return (
            <header className="main-header">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                    <div className="navbar-custom-menu">
                        {navigate}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to test it now

Comment: Ah I'm going to edit your answer a bit now to what I've done to get it working but I still have a problem where logging in gives me a problem where it doesn't change straight upon logging in, I have to refresh the page first before it shows which make me unsure if this is actually best practice. But it probably doesn't matter because down the line I'm going  to be rerouting to the homepage upon logging in anyway.

Comment: you want to re-render ?

Comment: Yeah basically!  Is there a simple function for that?  This kind of branches out to another question so I'll just do some research on it.

Comment: For this answer to work you will need to move the Meteor.userId() call into a container created with createContainer to maintain reactivity.